# What's the quickest way to format a drive (USB, HDD, Floppy) under Linux?

Tags: linux, formatting, format, fdisk

I had fdisk segfault and just wondered if anyone had any other options?

EDIT: It was late and that was a dumb question. Good answer though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fdisk is for partitioning drives. To format a drive, you would use the mkfs command. You need to specify the filesystem type using the -t option. I believe the default is ext2. The mkfs man page will explain more.

Example:

```
# mkfs -t vfat /dev/sda1
```

Comment: Note that gnu-fdisk can create a filesystem in addition to partitioning disks (and also resize, copy and move partitions).

Comment: Aye, it appears that gnu-fdisk is a reimplementation of the util-linux fdisk based on libparted. I suspect that most distributions ship util-linux fdisk by standard. You might as well use parted as that has a much nicer user interface than fdisk, which frankly wouldn't be hard. :)

Answer (score 1):

If fdisk segfaults, then try cfdisk or sfdisk.